# Can I define a linear gradient in SVG with a normal/bell-shaped blend?

Tags: graphics, svg, linear-gradients, svg-filters

Consider the following svg snippet:

```
<linearGradient id="redgradient" x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="0%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffffff"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>
</linearGradient>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" fill="url(#redgradient)"/>
```

Is there a way of specifying that the colours should be blended together using a bell shaped curve?
(Similar to the [GDI+ LinearGradientBrush::SetBlendBellShape method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535343(VS.85).aspx))

The two rectangles below show the difference - **left is without** bell blend, **right is with** bell blend:

[image]

Or is it left to the SVG renderer to decide how the colors should be blended together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a [`gradientTransform` to a linear gradient](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#LinearGradientElementGradientTransformAttribute). I'm not sure how the [available transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) map to your required effect.

If that doesn't work you can use the gradient as the input to a [filter](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html) and perhaps end up with a similar effect.  Here's [an article which covers combining filters](https://jbt.io/blog/svg-shinies-3/).

Comment: +1 thanks robert - I will do some experimenting to see if I can create a nicer linear gradient that the standard using a filter.

Comment: article doesn't exist

Answer (score 3):

gradientTransform cannot do this kind of transformation. You will need a 
filter to apply a bell shaped transform to a red/white gradient.

[image].

Original on the left, transformed on the right. The curve isn't very fine grained (only 15 values), so you would probably want to use more terms for a large gradient.

```
  <svg width="500px" height="500px" viewbox="0 0 800 800">
  <defs>
    <filter id="bellTransform" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feComponentTransfer>
       <feFuncG type="table" tableValues=
               "0.0000 0.0059 0.0166 0.0346 0.0628 0.1038 0.1586 0.2259 0.3011 0.3761 0.4406 0.4844 0.5000 0.5156 0.5594 0.6239 0.6989 0.7741 0.8414 0.8962 0.9372 0.9654 0.9834 0.9941 1.0000"/>
       <feFuncB type="table" tableValues=
               "0.0000 0.0059 0.0166 0.0346 0.0628 0.1038 0.1586 0.2259 0.3011 0.3761 0.4406 0.4844 0.5000 0.5156 0.5594 0.6239 0.6989 0.7741 0.8414 0.8962 0.9372 0.9654 0.9834 0.9941 1.0000"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      </filter>
  </defs>

  <linearGradient id="redgradient" x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="0%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffffff"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>
</linearGradient>
<rect filter="url(#bellTransform)" x="410" y="0" width="400" height="400" fill="url(#redgradient)"/>

<rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" fill="url(#redgradient)"/>

</svg>
```